# ESP12 Voltage Divider on ADC for battery capacity

Tags: batteries, adc, voltage-divider, esp8266

Since I received GREAT feedback on my first PCB design [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/290450/esp-breakout-pcb-design-kicad-questions) (and it works!) I have decided to design a second (improved) version.

In this version I would like to be able to measure the **source battery voltage** so I can translate that to an estimated battery capacity.
For this I'd like to use the **ADC** pin on the ESP12. On this pin I made a **voltage divider** because it only measures up to 1V.

Is this a working and the best approach for a beginner to estimate source battery capacity on the ESP12?

Someone suggested placing a .1Uf capacitor between GND and where the ADC reads. What would this do?

To get around the strain on the battery caused by this divider setup, should I put it behind a NPN tranistor?

[image]
[image]

the source files are all in [the project on GitHub](https://github.com/Thijxx/ESP12Board)

**Trace Thickness**
[image]

Did I make a mistake here?

**EDIT - Thicker traces and antenna free**
It also looks like this voltage divider is ok, I have tested it on a breadboard. The voltage divider power consumption is 0.0074mA if I calculated that right :)
[[image: Thicker traces and antenna free][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtlul.png)

Comment: The traces are soooo tiny, make it wider!

Comment: Please elaborate!

Comment: 0.0983mil? It's a 2.5um! 2.5 micrometer! It's a thick of a hair! The rules of thumb: low voltage signal traces - 8 to 30mils, power lines - 50 or more mils, for ground - plane.

Comment: Thank you! This is all almost 10mil, I use the OSH Park KiCad template. I will update the power traces to 50mil and double check de trace width in KiCad.